# RecyclerView item transition to DetailsFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-recyclerview, android-transitions

I am trying to create transition from single RecyclerView item to new DetailsFragment.
This is my situation:

Layout hierarchy:

```
 (Lvl1) MainActivity (fragment_container)
      (Lvl2) HomeFragment
           (Lvl3) ViewPager
                (Lvl4) AnotherFragment
                     (Lvl5) RecyclerView
                         (Lvl6) CardView (transitionName="item")
      (Lvl2) DetailsFragment
           (Lvl3) RelativeLayout (transitionName="item")
```

So, when item inside RecyclerView is clicked, fragmentTransaction will replace HomeFragment with DetailsFragment and what i want to achieve is "changeBounds" from CardView to RelativeLayout while HomeFragment is fadingOut and DetailsFragment in fadingIn.

My solution can be seen below and problem that i have is that DetailsFragment is instantly shown in background on transaction commit. Clicked CardView remains visible (above DetailsFragment) and it is fading as it should, but without any changes in dimension or position. All other CardViews are invisible during this operation.

It is obvious that i do not undesrstand something here and it is not working as it should...

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java -> OnRecyclerViewItemClick

```
@Override
public void onRecyclerViewClick(int position, int key) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                Fade fadeOutTransition = new Fade(Fade.OUT);
                fadeOutTransition.setDuration(2000);
                Fade fadeInTransition = new Fade(Fade.IN);
                fadeInTransition.setStartDelay(2000);
                fadeInTransition.setDuration(10000);

                ChangeBounds changeBoundsTransition = new ChangeBounds();
                changeBoundsTransition.setDuration(10000);

                homeFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(changeBoundsTransition);
                homeFragment.setReenterTransition(fadeInTransition);
                homeFragment.setExitTransition(fadeOutTransition);

                frag.setEnterTransition(fadeInTransition);
                frag.setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(false);
                frag.setAllowReturnTransitionOverlap(false);
                frag.setSharedElementEnterTransition(changeBoundsTransition);                   

                ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)((FrameLayout)homeFragment.getView()).getChildAt(0);
                RelativeLayout pagerLayout = (RelativeLayout) pager.getChildAt(0);
                RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView)pagerLayout.getChildAt(0);

                View view  = recycler.getChildAt(position);     

 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .addSharedElement(view  , "item")
            .commit();
```

Comment: Any luck solving this issue?

Comment: @ShahraizT. at the moment of writing this question, I had to give up on this feature since it wasn't critical. Still, I'd like to know if this is possible at all. Simpler examples work like a charm of course :)